# How do I make plots with custom axis lengths?

Tags: plotting

Is there a way make a plot's axes smaller than the `PlotRange` (other than drawing them manually as lines)?

Comment: `ImagePadding`? Not sure what you're after exactly. Can you post a sample pic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a combination of `ImagePadding` and `PlotRangeClipping -> False`:

```
Show[
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-.5, .5}}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 170}, {50, 50}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]